# What scripts and other files I need to be able to show user presence and person card?

Tags: javascript, css, script, presence-indication

I have a page with no resource links. What SharePoint script and style files I need to show user presence indicator and to use a function ProcessImn() correctly?

Now I have only a presence status square, but it is not working. I need some .js and .css files.